# npm fetch artifacts from local artifactory repository

Tags: node.js, npm

I just published my nodejs app (`customer-api`) to artifactory with `npm publish`. I have a `.npmrc` in the repo level.

```
cat .npmrc
_auth = ___
always-auth = true
email = Prayag.Upd@duwamish.com
```

I can see the published nodejs artifact in artifactory UI, along with the `*.tgz` file.

Now I can want to use `customer-api` in another project dependency which I tried as

```
  "publishConfig": {                                                                                   
    "registry": "https://code.duwamish.com/artifactory/api/npm/prayagupd-local-origin"                 
  },
  "dependencies": {                                                                                    
    "customer-api": "0.10.1",                                                                    
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",                                                                                   
    "express": "^4.16.1",                                                                              
    "formidable": "^1.0.17",                                                                           
    "immutable": "^3.8.2"                                                                              
  }
```

And obviously it is not going to work because I only have set [`publishConfig`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig) which is for `npm publish` not `npm install`.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: customer-api@0.10.1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/prayagupd/.npm/_logs/2018-06-27T05_46_03_812Z-debug.log
```

I could not find any documentation for pulling dependency from artifactory repo - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Can I set the npm repo to pull the artifacts from within `package.json`?

Comment: Can you confirm that the node.js artifact is showing in the web ui? And if so, is the name similar to the specified version? What is the name inside `package.json`, and do you have a `version` parameter?